# Can I separate an NSString by more than 1 separator?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I would like to separate my string by spaces, commas, periods (ie. punctuations). I am using:

```
[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

to separate by spaces, but need to be able to split by punctuations as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` with a character set made up of whatever characters you want to split by.

Comment: Thanks I tried: 

[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,.?!"];

and that did the trick

Comment: Sheehan Alam: The space character is not the only whitespace character, and those four are not the only punctuation characters. Start with the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`, make a mutable copy (and don't forget to release or autorelease it), and union in the `punctuationCharacterSet`. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableCharacterSet/formUnionWithCharacterSet: